# makefile works with cygwin on windows but not ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cross-platform

I have the following folder on my git repo - https://github.com/ryu577/base/tree/master/numerical/c/NumericalRecipiesCode/lib

On my windows machine which has cygwin installed, I can run make in that directory, which triggers the command -

```
gcc -o ../bin/lib/tst_libfns ../obj/nrutil.o ../obj/fileio.o ../obj/tst_libfns.o -I ../include -lm
```

This puts the tst_libfns.o and fileio.o in the obj directory.

Now, I pulled this repository into my ubuntu machine and tried the same thing. However, when the same command is generated there, it gives me the following error:

```
gcc -o ../bin/lib/tst_libfns ../obj/nrutil.o ../obj/fileio.o ../obj/tst_libfns.o -I../include -lm
../obj/fileio.o:fileio.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `__getreent'
../obj/tst_libfns.o:tst_libfns.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../bin/lib/tst_libfns] Error 1
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out. I had pulled in the .o files through git in the obj directory and gcc was somehow trying to use the existing files (which had been generated in Cygwin + Windows). Somehow, those .o files don't seem to be compatible with linux. When I delete them and run the make command again, the .o files are re-generated. I guess the moral of the story here is that binaries and executables generated by GCC in Windows are incompatible with Linux (and I'll guess vice versa).

Comment: Definitely they're incompatible.  You can't run Mac programs on Windows, Windows programs on Linux, Linux programs on Mac, etc. (at least not without special software installed to "fake" compatibility).  Also, you should never commit object files and binaries to your source code control system like git: source code control systems are for source code.